# Visual Studio Code integrated terminal is defaulting to PowerShell Core

Tags: powershell, terminal, visual-studio-code

I have recently installed [PowerShell Core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell#PowerShell_Core_6.0) v6.  I wanted to check it out and see what it is like and it is easy to switch to in [Windows Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Terminal) if I want to play with it.  After installing Version 6 though, Visual Studio Code keeps using core for my integrated console, despite my *[settings.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65908987/how-can-i-open-visual-studio-codes-settings-json-file)* file pointing to the *powershell.exe* file in [System32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_folder#List_of_special_folders).  How can I fix this?

Our environment is all on version 5.1 and core is missing many features and cmdlets that are in 5.1.  I need these when testing scripts I will deploy.  I can add another terminal and it will use PowerShell 5.1, but since it is not integrated, running script blocks fails sometimes. Here is my *settings.json* file:

```json
{
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "powershell.powerShellDefaultVersion": "Windows Powershell (x64)",
    "editor.accessibilitySupport": "off"
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`"terminal.integrated.shell.windows"` applies to the integrated general-purpose terminal that is not specific to any particular development language.

You're looking for the <del>`"powershell.powerShellExePath"`</del>  setting that is specific to the [PowerShell extension for Visual Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell) and determines what PowerShell executable is used for the so-called *PowerShell Integrated Console* (PIC), which provides special features for PowerShell development and debugging.

**Update**: The **`powershell.powerShellExePath`** setting is now **deprecated**.

- See the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60555493/45375) for the current solution, which describes both the `settings.json` method and the GUI method of controlling what PowerShell edition is used in the PIC.

---

**Original, now obsolete answer:**

Therefore, to make the PowerShell Integrated Console run Windows PowerShell, use:

```json
"powershell.powerShellExePath": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
```

---

Note: The first time in a session you activate an editor tab in which a file with PowerShell code is loaded, the PowerShell Integrated Console is loaded *and remains active* even when you switch to a non-PowerShell editor tab.

Use the Terminal panel's pop-up list in its top right corner to switch between running shells, e.g., in order to return to the integrated terminal's shell:

[image: running shells]