# How can I start Powershell script as noprofile in Visual Studio Code

Tags: powershell, shell, visual-studio-code

How can I start Powershell script as noprofile in Visual Studio Code, I can run the Powershell Ise with noprofile with command **PowerShell_Ise -NoProfile** . But howcan we do the same for a poershell session in Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 20):

- If you're **running PowerShell in the PIC (*PowerShell Integrated Console*)**, which is a *special* shell that comes with the [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell):

  - To turn off profile loading in this special shell, make sure that the
    `PowerShell: Enable Profile Loading` option for the PowerShell extension is *unchecked* (via `File > Preferences > Settings`, <kbd>Ctrl-,</kbd>).
  - See the bottom section for how to control which particular PowerShell edition / executable is used in the PIC (PowerShell Integrated Console).
- If you're **running PowerShell as a *general-purpose shell*** in Visual Studio Code's integrated terminal:

  - You'll have to modify the default PowerShell *shell profile* or add a custom profile, with an `"args"` argument value of `[ "-noprofile" ]`, by direct editing of the JSON file underlying the settings, `settings.json` (`>Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)` from the command palette).
  - The following shows a relevant `settings.json` excerpt with a modified default PowerShell profile that suppresses profile loading.

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "PowerShell": {
      "source": "PowerShell",
      "icon": "terminal-powershell",
      "args": [ "-noprofile" ]  // suppress profile loading
    },  // ...
}
```

Read on for detailed, general information about shells and terminals in Visual Studio Code.

---

#### Overview of shell and terminal settings in Visual Studio Code:

- **3 different types of shells apply intrinsically**:

  - The default shell for the ***integrated terminal*** (the `TERMINAL` tab of the panel).

    - *Optionally*, the ***automation shell*** to use for automation tasks (defined in `tasks.json`) instead of the default integrated-terminal shell.
  - The default shell for opening an ***external terminal*** (`> Open New External Terminal`); note that on Windows you can specify a shell executable *directly*, but on Unix-like platforms you must specify a *terminal application*, which *itself* then determines the shell to launch - see details below.
- With the **[PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell)** installed, yet another shell applies:

  - The specific PowerShell executable to use for the **PIC (*PowerShell Integrated Console*)**, which provides tight integration with editing and support for debugging PowerShell code.

These shells:

- can all be configured separately
- may differ in their default behavior
- only *some* of them allow you to specify *startup parameters*, such as `-NoProfile` in your case.
- The ***default* shells** are:

  - For the *integrated* terminal and running tasks:

    - Windows: **PowerShell**.

      - Note that if a *PowerShell (Core) 6+* version is found to be installed, it takes precedence over the built-in *Windows PowerShell* edition.
    - Unix-like platforms: the **user's default shell**, as reflected in the **`SHELL`** environment variable.
  - For the *external* terminal:

    - Windows: `conhost.exe`, which launches `cmd.exe` (Command Prompt)
    - Unix-like platforms: the host platform's default terminal application, such as `Terminal.app` on macOS, which *itself* determines what shell to launch (though, by default, it is also the user's default shell).
    - Note: On Windows only you may specify a *shell* (rather than a *terminal*) executable directly (e.g., `bash.exe`), in which case it opens in a regular console window (`conhost.exe`)

The following **excerpt from a `Settings.json` file** (`> Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)`) shows the relevant settings for each (as of VSCode v1.60 / PowerShell Extension v2021.8.2):

- In *earlier* VSCode versions, the `"terminal.integrated.shell.*"` and `"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.*"` settings determined the default shell and its startup arguments for the integrated terminal. These have been superseded by [shell *profiles*](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_configuring-profiles), defined via `"terminal.integrated.profiles.*"` properties, and an associated `"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.*"` property that contains the *name* of the profile to use *by default*, as shown below.

```json
{ 

  // ...

  // **General-purpose integrated-terminal shell**.

  // Shell *profiles* define the *available* shells for the integrated terminal.
  // This property is situationally created automatically, platform-appropriately,
  // based on what shells VSCode finds in standard locations on your 
  // system.
  // However, it *need not be present* in a given file - VSCode
  // knows about about *standard* profiles *implicitly* when it
  // comes to choosing a default shell.
  // This example applies to Windows, and shows that Git Bash
  // was found on the system.
  // On Unix-like platforms, replace ".windows" with ".osx" or ".linux", 
  // as appropriate.
  // To add custom profiles:
  //   * In file *paths*, use "\\" or "/" as the path separator.
  //   * Use an "args" array property to specify start-up arguments, if necessary.
  "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
      "PowerShell": {
        "source": "PowerShell",
        "icon": "terminal-powershell"
      },
      "Command Prompt": {
        "path": [
          "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
          "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
        ],
        "args": [],
        "icon": "terminal-cmd"
      },
      "Git Bash": {
        "source": "Git Bash"
      }
  }

  // Define the *default* shell profile, which serves as the default
  // shell in the *integrated terminal* and - except
  // if overridden, as shown below - also for *tasks*.
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "PowerShell"  
  
  // **Automation-tasks shell**,
  // for the tasks defined in "tasks.json" and for debugging:
  // This definition is *optional* and *overrides* the default shell configured above.
  // Note: 
  //  * The *executable file path* must be specified (just the file name is sufficient for executables present in %PATH%);
  //    that is, this setting doesn't reference the shell *profiles*.
  //  * While "args" technically allows you to pass startup arguments,
  //     tasks will *blindly append* "/d /c <command>" (for "cmd.exe")
  //     "-Command <command>" (for PowerShell) to these startup arguments,
  //     which can *break* the overall invocation if the args
  //     you specify include *commands* to execute, not just *options*.
  // Note: "terminal.integrated.automationShell.<platform>" is DEPRECATED.
  "terminal.integrated.automationProfile.windows": {
     "path": "cmd.exe"
  }

  // **External-terminal executable**:
  // The *terminal program* to use for opening an external terminal window, which itself determines what shell to launch.
  // (> Open New External Terminal).
  // Note: 
  //  * The *executable file path* must be specified (just the file name is sufficient for executables present in %PATH%);
  //  * There is NO way to pass startup arguments.
  //  * This example specifies Windows Terminal (wt.exe).
  //   * On Windows only, you may also specify a *shell* executable directly,
  //     which then opens in a regular console window (conhost.exe)
  "terminal.external.windowsExec": "wt.exe",

  // **PowerShell Integrated Console**:
  // Profile loading is *disabled* by default; you can enable it here, but 
  // note that the PowerShell Integrated Console has its own, 
  // separate $PROFILE location, which differs from the one in a 
  // regular console window. If you want to load your regular profile, 
  // place the following statement in the $PROFILE file of 
  // the Integrated Console:
  //    . ($PROFILE -replace '\.VSCode', '.PowerShell')
  // (Open the profile file for editing by submitting the following command 
  // from the Integrated Console: 
  //    code $PROFILE
  // )
  "powershell.enableProfileLoading": false,
  
  // ...

}
```

---

**If you want to configure the PIC (*PowerShell Integrated Console*) to use a *different PowerShell edition / version***:

<sup>Note: Written as of version `v2022.6.3` of the PowerShell extension.</sup>

**GUI** method:

- Make sure that a PowerShell source-code file is the active editor.
- Click on `{}` in the status bar (the bottom right corner), then click on `Show PowerShell Session Menu` in the tooltip window that pops up, as shown below.

  - Alternatively, irrespective of whether the active editor contains PowerShell source code or not, submit `PowerShell: Show Session Menu` in the command palette to open the relevant menu.

[image: PowerShell session menu activator])

- *If* the session menu is *pinned* as an icon (use the pushpin icon on the right edge of the tooltip window to toggle), it looks something like this, reflecting the active version *number*, and clicking it *directly* opens the PowerShell session menu in the command palette:

[image: PowerShell pinned session menu icon])

- This opens the **PowerShell session menu** in the command palette: Choose from the other available versions, if any, which are prefixed with `Switch to:`, which *makes that version the default going forward*.
- If the version / edition of interest isn't shown, you must add its executable path either via the Settings GUI - by selecting `Modify list of additional PowerShell locations` from the PowerShell session menu - or via your `settings.json` file (see next section).

**Via `settings.json`** (`> Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)`):

- The `powershell.powerShellAdditionalExePaths` setting is a *single object* that allows you to add the full executable paths of PowerShell versions that the extension couldn't find automatically by *self-chosen property names* - see example below.
- The `powershell.powerShellDefaultVersion` property determines which version to use *by default*, which is either the name of property of the `powershell.powerShellAdditionalExePaths` setting or that of an auto-discovered version, as shown in the session menu. Selecting a `Switch to:` entry from the menu automatically updates this setting.

```json
{ 

  // ...

  // The paths to any PowerShell executables that the extension cannot auto-discover.
  // The property names are self-chosen names, which show in the
  // PowerShell session menu.
  // Note: 
  //  * Executable paths only are supported, not also arguments.
  //  * If a value isn't a valid executable path, it is ignored,
  //    and the version doesn't show up in the session menu.
  // In the status bar, the currently active version is displayed by its actual characteristics,
  //  not by these self-chosen property names; e.g., 
  //  "PowerShell 7.2")
  "powershell.powerShellAdditionalExePaths": { 
      "Latest Preview": "C:\\Users\\jdoe\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\powershell\\pwsh.exe" 
  },

  // The PowerShell version to use by default, which can be
  // a property name from "powershell.powerShellAdditionalExePaths" or
  // the name of an auto-discovered version, as show in the PowerShell
  // session menu.
  "powershell.powerShellDefaultVersion": "Latest Preview",

  // ...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go in powershell extension settings and remove check box at "PowerShell: Enable Profile Loading", i think it help. Also check task for runs powershell scripts with some parameters [discussion about task](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3519)