# How to add node terminal Visual Studio Code?

Tags: node.js, powershell, visual-studio-code

I yet succed this yet but I reinstall my Visual Studio Code and can't add node terminal to it again.

Please not say me I can run with bash also and use powershell. This two default reachable in Vscode.

But I would like change the deafult terminal and change to node terminal. Not powershell and not cmd...

I search very lot of website in this topic but vanish the solution.  There is solution. I used at today node terminal in vs code.

So i should see node instead powershell or cmd.

Sorry if explain lot of but I want be very clear...

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<sup>For an overview of *all* types of shells used in Visual Studio Code, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60555493/45375).</sup>

Custom shell profiles are maintained in the **`settings.json` file**; to open it for editing, select `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)` from the command palette (<kbd>Ctrl-Shift-P</kbd>).

There are ***platform-specific* properties named `terminal.integrated.profiles.*`, where `*` is either `windows`, `linux`, or `osx`** (macOS).

The properties inside each define ***shell profiles***, i.e. the **shells available for running in the integrated terminal** via the dropdown menu labeled `+` ([image: shell-selection dropdown]).

Each **shell-profile definition**:

- At a minimum requires either a `path` argument specifying the full path to the shell executable or, on Windows only, a `source` argument, which can be `PowerShell` or `Git Bash` to let VS Code find the appropriate executables.
- Start-up arguments are specified via `args`.
- For all supported properties, see [the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_configuring-profiles).

To **set the *default* shell profile**:

- *Either*: use the `Terminal: Select Default Profile` command from the command palette: a list of all defined profiles will present; select the one of interest.

  - Note: Clicking the cog icon ([image: cog icon]) to the right of each profile allows you to define a *new* profile that is a *based on* the highlighted one: You're prompted for a name for the new profile, which is then created as a *copy* of the highlighted profile. Note that no further action is taken as of v1.59 - you must manually open the `settings.json` file for editing in order to customize the new profile.
- *Or*: Set the platform-appropriate `terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.*` property to the name of the desired shell profile.

---

**Example: Defining Node.js (`node.exe`) as a custom shell profile on Windows:**

- Determine the full path to `node.exe` and escape `\` characters for JSON by doubling them; e.g., from PowerShell:

```bash
# Get node.exe's full path, escape '\' chars., copy to the clipboard.
(Get-Command node.exe).Path.Replace('\', '\\') | Set-Clipboard
```

- Add the following to your `settings.json` file (if the `terminal.integrated.profiles.windows` property already exists, simply *add* the `Node.js` property to it); the example uses `node.exe`'s default installation location, `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe`.

```json
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "Node.js": {
      "path": "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe",
      "args": [] // Add startup arguments as needed.
    }
  },

// Make Node.js the default shell (if the property already exists, update its value).
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Node.js",
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I try interpret that you write. But not work. Not offer "node" integrated terminal via the dropdown menu labeled + Only I do the folowing: 1. Open powershell 2. execution this command:(Get-Command node.exe).Path.Replace('\', '\\') | Set-Clipboard 3. Paste your code to Settings.json that was empty cause I clean cash before (with plus , sign cause this missing between up and botom code)

Comment: This is my settings.json file: {
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        "Node.js": {
          "path": "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe",
          "args": [] // Add startup arguments as needed.
        }
      },
    
     
    // Make Node.js the default shell (if the property already exists, update its value).
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Node.js",
  
}

Comment: I restart windows also

Comment: Success! I reopen the Visual Studio Code not there Node. But now I open a new folder and now there is! Thank you very much again!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out in the end, @MilánNikolics; my pleasure.

Comment: i got error `Unknown configuration setting`

Comment: @MahmoudMabrok: The solution still works (v1.77.3) - I just tried it. The error message suggests that there's a typo.