# Visual Studio Code is suddenly defaulting to PowerShell for integrated terminal and tasks

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, git-bash

When I woke up this morning and launched Visual Studio Code, my default terminal on launch, and when running tasks is now PowerShell, instead of [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway). I am on Windows. I have tried changing the [settings.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65908987/how-can-i-open-visual-studio-codes-settings-json-file) to no avail. Is there something I'm missing?

```
{
    "workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "rvest.vs-code-prettier-eslint"
    },
    "aws.samcli.location": "C:\\Users\\king\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\sam.exe",
    "typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
    "[html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
    },
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "diffEditor.maxComputationTime": 0,
    "extensions.ignoreRecommendations": true,
    "[typescript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "editor.renderControlCharacters": true,
    "[jsonc]": {

        "editor.quickSuggestions": {
            "strings": true
        },
        "editor.suggest.insertMode": "replace"
    },
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "editor.accessibilitySupport": "off",
    "workbench.editor.untitled.hint": "hidden",
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Git Bash",
    "terminal.external.windowsExec": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
    "terminal.explorerKind": "external",
    "terminal.integrated.automationShell.linux": ""
}
```

I found this [related Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60537341/how-can-i-start-powershell-script-as-noprofile-in-visual-studio-code/60555493#60555493) making the default PowerShell, but I didn't see anything that was incorrect about my setting...especially because my goal is the opposite—to stop PowerShell!

Comment: See my `Git Bash` settings at https://stackoverflow.com/a/69048033/836330.  You are using the deprecated form of the settings (but they should still work I believe).  But there has been another issue since the v1.60 release - see the link.

Comment: @Mark your git bash config worked great, I used it then added the line `"terminal.integrated.automationShell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"`

Comment: I thought I was going insane; glad I'm not the only one. I have to open my `settings.json` file, change something and save it again so it actually sets the default profile. It's so annoying, I hope they fix this soon.

Comment: I was about to go crazy with this error because I have tasks running in powershell but also Git Bash. Adding "terminal.integrated.automationShell.windows": "C:\\Program Files               \\Git\\bin\\bash.exe" to my settings solved the problem. Now both my powershell tasks and git bash tasks are working fine.

Comment: oh please this have broken my "restore terminal" workflow, i can confirm this bug happens after this update

Comment: I had a similar issue where my shell changed from pwsh7 to powershell5.  Fix here: https://rnelson0.com/2020/03/05/using-powershell-7-in-vs-code/.  New approach to this fix described here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_terminal-profiles

Answer (score 47, accepted):

*Update*: **Version v1.60.0 had a bug. Upgrade to v1.60.1 or higher for a fix**.

The bug manifested in the following **symptoms**:

- The `Open in Integrated Terminal` shortcut-menu command in the Explorer pane's shortcut always uses the built-in default shell (PowerShell on Windows), ignoring the configured one.
- The same goes for running tasks (with or without a separate `terminal.integrated.automationShell.*` setting).
- Also, if a given folder or workspace happened to have an integrated terminal open when quitting Visual Studio Code, the shell that is launched when the integrated terminal automatically reopens the next time is again the built-in default shell, not the configured one. By contrast, if reopening doesn't auto-open the integrated terminal, opening it manually *does* respect the configured default shell, and so does manually creating another shell instance later.

See [GitHub issue  #132150](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/132150)

The following information turned out to be unrelated to the bug, but is hopefully still useful general information about Visual Studio Code's recent change in how shells for the integrated terminal are configured:

---

##### Migrating from the legacy default shell settings to *shell profiles*:

- Recently, the **`"terminal.integrated.shell.*"` and `"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.*"` settings were *deprecated*** and replaced with a **more flexible model that allows defining *multiple* shells to select from**, via so-called **[shell *profiles*](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_configuring-profiles)**, optionally defined in setting `"terminal.integrated.profiles.*"`, with an associated mandatory `"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.*"` setting referencing the name of the profile to use *by default* - which may be an explicitly defined custom profile or one of the built-in, platform-appropriate default profiles.

  - Note: `*` in the setting names above represents the appropriate *platform identifier*, namely `windows`, `linux`, or `osx` (macOS).
- As of v1.60.1, if legacy `"terminal.integrated.shell.*"` settings are *also* present, the *new* settings take precedence (even though the tooltip when editing `"terminal.integrated.shell.*"` in `settings.json` suggests that this change is yet to come).

  - In the absence of *both* settings, **Visual Studio Code's *built-in* default shell** is used, which on **Windows** is ***PowerShell*,**<sup>[1]</sup> and on **Unix-like platforms** the user's default shell, as **specified in the `SHELL` environment variable**.
  - Recent Visual Studio Code versions, starting *before* v1.60 - seemingly as *one-time* opportunity - displayed a prompt offering to *migrate* the deprecated settings to the new ones.

    - *Accepting* the migration results in the following:

      - Creation of setting `"terminal.integrated.shell.*"` containing a custom shell profile derived from the values of legacy settings `"terminal.integrated.shell.*"` and, if present, `"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.*"`; that custom profile's name has the suffix  `(migrated)`
      - Creation of setting `terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.*` whose value is the migrated profile's name, making it the default shell.
      - Removal of legacy settings `"terminal.integrated.shell.*"` and `"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.*"`
    - If you *decline* the migration, you can later effectively perform it by re-choosing the default shell, as described below.

      - Note: The new `"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.*"` setting that is created in the process then effectively *overrides* the legacy `"terminal.integrated.shell.*"` and `"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.*"` settings, but the latter won't be removed automatically. To avoid confusion, it's best to remove them from `settings.json` manually.
- **Choose the *default shell profile* to use** in order to (re)specify the default shell:

  - Click on the down-arrow part of the shell-selector icon ([image: shell selector]) on the right side of the integrated terminal, select `Select Default Profile`, which presents a list of the defined profiles to select the default from - in the absence of explicitly defined profiles, *standard* profiles are offered (see below).
  - This translates into a `terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.*` setting in `settings.json`, whose value is the name of the chosen shell profile - which may be the name of a *built-in* profile or one of the ones explicitly defined in `"terminal.integrated.profiles.*"`
  - Note: This shell is by default also used for *tasks* (defined in `tasks.json`), but that can be overridden with a `"terminal.integrated.automationShell.*"` setting pointing to the executable of an alternative shell.
- *Optionally*, in your `settings.json` file, you may **create a platform-appropriate `terminal.integrated.profiles.*` setting with [shell profiles](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_configuring-profiles) of interest**:

  - Note: Even if your `settings.json` contains *no* (platform-appropriate) `"terminal.integrated.profiles.*"` setting, Visual Studio code has built-in *standard* profiles it knows of and offers them for selection when choosing the *default* shell.

    - These standard profiles are a mix of shells that come with the host platform as well as some that Visual Studio detects dynamically on a given system, such as Git Bash on Windows.
  - To **create the *standard* profiles *explicitly***, do the following:

    - Note: You may choose to do this in order to *customize* the standard profiles. However, if your intent is merely to *add* custom profiles - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68791496/45375) for an example - it isn't necessary to create the standard profiles inside the `"terminal.integrated.profiles.*"` setting, because Visual Studio Code knows about them even if not explicitly defined.
    - Via `File > Preferences > Settings` (<kbd>Ctrl-,</kbd>), search for `profiles` and click on `Edit in settings.json` below the platform-appropriate `Terminal > Integrated > Profiles > *` setting; this will open `settings.json` for editing, with the standard profiles added; simply saving the file is sufficient.

      - Note: If the `"terminal.integrated.profiles.*"` setting shown doesn't contain the expected, platform-appropriate standard profiles, a setting by that name may already be present; to force creation of the standard profiles, remove or comment out the existing setting and save the file, then try again.
    - On Windows, you'll end up with something like the following:

      ```json
      "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        "PowerShell": {
          "source": "PowerShell",
          "icon": "terminal-powershell"
        },
        "Command Prompt": {
          "path": [
            "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
            "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
          ],
          "args": [],
          "icon": "terminal-cmd"
        },
        "Git Bash": {
          "source": "Git Bash"
        }
      }
      ```

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60537341/how-can-i-start-powershell-script-as-noprofile-in-visual-studio-code/60555493#60555493) you link to in your question, which provides an **overview of the various types of shells used in Visual Studio Code**, has been updated to reflect the information about the new shell profiles.

---

<sup>[1] Note: If a *PowerShell (Core) v6+* installation is found, it takes precedence over the built-in *Windows PowerShell* version.</sup>

Answer (score 6):

**Note:** Now this bug has been fixed in Visual Studio Code. Just update your Visual Studio Code to the latest version. (*17-Sep-2021*)

---

I have a temporary solution.

First paste this code in *[settings.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65908987/how-can-i-open-visual-studio-codes-settings-json-file)* and save.

```
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Git Bash",

"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
 "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe": {
  "path": "",
  "args": []
 }
},
```

Before closing Visual Studio Code, select `Output` instead of `Terminal`.

1. Now you can open Visual Studio Code
2. After Visual Studio Code is loaded, you need to click on Terminal. After this, you will now see [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29).
3. Select output before whenever you close Visual Studio Code.

Reference: [Visual Studio Code is suddenly defaulting to PowerShell for integrated terminal instead of $Bash in Windows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iOl8tvYgegQ)

**Note:** *This is not an solution. I shared this because maybe it can save you from getting disappointed.*

Answer (score 4):

You can always download and install previous releases from the official website https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_59 (currently at the top).

As version 1.60 was bugged, v1.59 is a good candidate.

### Disable automatic updates

Explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50162685/how-do-i-disable-vs-code-of-updating-itself).

1. Open User Settings `File > Preferences > Settings`.
2. Add `"update.mode": "none"` to your settings.

### Install older version

Afterwards you can just overwrite current version with the installation of downloaded version.

**Note**: Wait for next version to fix it, so remember you had automatic update disabled!

Comment: when you install the older version make sure to put back this setting

"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\<path to Git>\\bin\\bash.exe"

Comment: I just installed v1.59 as normal and I didn't have to add anything to json settings and it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but I try to run the command prompt. I fix it by adding this to the *...\Code\User\settings.json* file:

> "terminal.integrated.automationShell.windows": "cmd.exe",

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to [issue 138999](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/138999) which will add a mitigation/enhancement to Visual Studio Code 1.70 (July 2022) with [PR 154290](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/154290) and [commit 91b82c0](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/91b82c0f0b9d0c9a9135252663522a563be3f6eb)

> ### increase barrier for available profiles to be ready
>
> Wait up to 20 seconds for profiles to be ready so it's assured that we know the actual default terminal before launching the first terminal.
> This isn't expected to ever take this long.

For Visual Studio Code with synchronized user settings, the profile might take more time than expected to fully load, hence the advantage of that workaround.

Answer (score -1):

I simply replaced [CMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) by [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway) :-) in the *[settings.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65908987/how-can-i-open-visual-studio-codes-settings-json-file)* file:

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "PowerShell": {
        "source": "PowerShell",
        "icon": "terminal-powershell"
    },
    "Command Prompt": {
        "path": [
            //"${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
            //"${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
            "C:\\PrivateProgramms\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"
        ],
        "args": [],
        "icon": "terminal-cmd"
    },
   "Git Bash": {
        "source": "Git Bash"
        //"path": [  "C:\\PrivateProgramms\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe" ],
        //"args": [],
        //"icon": "terminal-cmd"
    }
},
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt"
```