# Visual Studio Code Opens and run scripts on the non-default terminal

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, cmd, terminal

Until yesterday, my VSC worked fine. I opened, edited, and run my python scripts without a problem.
However since today when I start my VSC session, it starts on Powershell Terminal, that doesn't recognize my conda enviroment despite I set the default terminal as cmd:

[image]

[image]

When I open the cmd terminal manually, automatically loads my conda env, however when I run the command "Run Python File in terminal" it always opens on Powershell

[image]

Any suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: See if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69050730/45375) helps. If so, we can close your question as a duplicate.