# How to Change Visual Studio Code Terminal Default Permanently

Tags: bash, terminal, visual-studio-code

I've changed the terminal type of my Visual Studio Code to Bash (shown in the below picture). Somehow Visual Studio Code loads powershell each time I load Visual Studio Code automatically. If I click the plus sign to open default terminal, I do get the Bash loaded. Where can I change the setting to initially load Bash? It was loading Bash initially too just fine up until recently...

[image]

Comment: It is a known bug, hopefully it will be fixed soon.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VSCode is suddenly defaulting to powershell for integrated terminal and tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69047142/vscode-is-suddenly-defaulting-to-powershell-for-integrated-terminal-and-tasks)