# VS Code: After the latest update, the default terminal is Power Shell, ignoring the default settings

Tags: visual-studio-code

I found suddenly I have all my terminal set up to PS without any reason. I found how to change the default settings, changed them, restarted VS Code, but still, PS is loaded as a default despite the settings: see the picture. How to make it load cmd?

[image]

I also changed the settings:

[image]

The current version is
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VSCode is suddenly defaulting to powershell for integrated terminal and tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69047142/vscode-is-suddenly-defaulting-to-powershell-for-integrated-terminal-and-tasks)

Comment: @TimothyG. The most rated answer doesn't work for me: it suggested using UI or settings.json what both I did and nothing worked.