# Change which PowerShell edition is used for temporary integrated console in VSCode?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

The following setting let's you configure that each deugging session should start it's own temporary integrated console.

```json
"powershell.debugging.createTemporaryIntegratedConsole": true
```

Problem however is that this always creates `PS Core` session and I would like temporary session to be `Windows PowerShell`

I have configured which terminal is default in user settings like this:

```json
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "PowerShell Core": {
        "path": "C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7\\pwsh.exe",
        "color": "terminal.ansiRed",
        "overrideName": true
    },
    "Windows PowerShell": {
        "path": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
        "color": "terminal.ansiBlue",
        "overrideName": true
    }
},
// Use Windows PowerShell by default
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Windows PowerShell",
```

However this works only when you manually create a new session in `VSCode`,
but temporary console used by the debugger is still `PS Core`

`launch.json` doesn't allow `console` property to be set for debugger provided by `PowerShell extension`

How do I force temporary debugging console to use `Windows PowerShell`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The `"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows"` settings are for *general-purpose* shells running in Visual Studio Code's integrated terminal.
- The *special-purpose* shell that comes with the [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell), the so-called PowerShell Integrated Console (PIC), is what enables debugging, and its settings are *separate* from those for the general-purpose shells.

See the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60555493/45375) for how to control what PowerShell edition is used in the PIC.