# Visual Studio Code Powershell Terminal Output Text Color

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, terminal

My powershell terminal suddenly changed its header text color from green to white color.

**Actions Taken:** Reinstalled visual studio, deleted .code settings/config directory after uninstallation.

I want to return the Green and White color to easily distinguish the output result.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you've accidentally reverted to an earlier version of PowerShell. See if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60555493/45375) helps.

Answer (score 0):

There might be several reasons for this:

1. If this is also affecting your PowerShell console, it's probably related to PSReadLine and your PowerShell Profile. If this is the case, have a look at `Get-PSReadLineOption` to compare your settings and Set-PSreadLine.

[image: PSReadLine Options]

More info about PSReadLine: [Set-PSReadLineOption | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/set-psreadlineoption?view=powershell-7.3)

Customizations can be stored in your powershell profile, which can be edited in VSCode with this oneliner:

```
code $PROFILE
```

2. Your terminal color settings in VSCode have been edited. Using [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[P], search for the option `Terminal: Change color...` There is an option in there called `reset to default` Please be aware you need to have a terminal session opened in VSCode for the options to appear
3. The default profile for terminal changed. Using [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[P], search for the option `Terminal: Select default profile`